# Capybara and Rails have_content failing in spec to test to see if a messages partial appears

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I have a request spec which passes up until the point where I need to check to see if content is present on the page, which I am using `page.should have_content` to do. The content is actually a message which appears on successful form submission, which is rendered from a messages partial. The test fails even though If I test through the browser, functionality works as expected and the content appears as it should. I'm also using FactoryGirl to generate the users to use for the form submission.

Here's the error I get after running the spec with the --format d option:

```
UserSignup
  shows a thank you message on successful form submission (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) UserSignup shows a thank you message on successful form submission
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content("Thank you. You will be notified of our launch at #{user.email}.")
       expected #has_content?("Thank you. You will be notified of our launch at quinn.purdy@casperzboncak.org.") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_signup_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

user_signup_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "UserSignup" do
   it "shows a thank you message on successful form submission" do
     user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     visit sign_up_path
     fill_in "user_fullname", with: user.fullname
     fill_in "user_email", with: user.email
     click_button "Sign up"
     current_path.should eq(sign_up_path)
     page.should have_content("Thank you. You will be notified of our launch at #{user.email}.")
   end
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

def create
    @user = User.new(secure_params)
    if @user.valid?
    @user.subscribe
    flash[:notice] = "Thank you. You will be notified of our launch at #{@user.email}."
    redirect_to sign_up_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end


private

  def secure_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:fullname, :email)
  end

end
```

I'm wondering if it could be because I render the messages partial from the application layout, but when it gets outputted in the users view, the message appears inside the `body` of the source, but outside the `main` class.

Comment: have you tried 'expect(page).to have_content "Thank you. You will be notified of our launch at #{user.email}."'? How about sticking pry in your gem file, requiring it 'require "pry"' and adding binding.pry under your page.should line.  then type page (enter) and see what it says.

Comment: You can also use `puts page.body` and `save_and_open_page` to see what the capybara page content is at any point (note: the latter requires the `launchy` gem to be installed.

Comment: Also, do you have any uniqueness validation in your User?  The `FactoryGirl.create` call will actually save that user to the DB, so the one you're trying to sign up through the page may be clashing.

Comment: @Anko  Added, pry but it doesn't run if it's below the failing line in the spec. If I add it above the page.should line then it runs. Currently I do have the line set to 'expect(page).to have_content' but it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seem to have got the tests passing by adding the line `, :js => true do` beside 'it' and using the selenium web driver. There's got to be a way to do it without selenium I'm thinking, because you have to sit and wait while it actually runs it in a browser which is the downside.

Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way, and I should actually be checking for the partial in a view spec (currently it was just part of the feature test).